# ManualMap inject a DLL from Resources in C++

Tags: c++, code-injection, loadlibrary

I am learning C++ and I need help figuring out how to inject a DLL with ManualMap Injection from the C++ Projects resources.

I have a source for this in C#, but I am not sure how to convert it, and I don't want to try to convert about 5000 lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a undetected DLL Injection using ManualMapping it's undetected by many GameGuard's for injecting DLL's into games.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h> /* PROCESSENTRY32 */
#include <conio.h> /* _getch() */
#include <shlwapi.h> /* StrStrI */

#pragma comment(lib, "shlwapi.lib") /* unresolved external symbol __imp__StrStrIW@8 */

typedef HMODULE (WINAPI *pLoadLibraryA)(LPCSTR);
typedef FARPROC (WINAPI *pGetProcAddress)(HMODULE,LPCSTR);

typedef BOOL (WINAPI *PDLL_MAIN)(HMODULE,DWORD,PVOID);

typedef struct _MANUAL_INJECT
{
    PVOID ImageBase;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS NtHeaders;
    PIMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION BaseRelocation;
    PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR ImportDirectory;
    pLoadLibraryA fnLoadLibraryA;
    pGetProcAddress fnGetProcAddress;
}MANUAL_INJECT,*PMANUAL_INJECT;

DWORD WINAPI LoadDll(PVOID p)
{
    PMANUAL_INJECT ManualInject;

    HMODULE hModule;
    DWORD i,Function,count,delta;

    PDWORD ptr;
    PWORD list;

    PIMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION pIBR;
    PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR pIID;
    PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME pIBN;
    PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA FirstThunk,OrigFirstThunk;

    PDLL_MAIN EntryPoint;

    ManualInject=(PMANUAL_INJECT)p;

    pIBR=ManualInject->BaseRelocation;
    delta=(DWORD)((LPBYTE)ManualInject->ImageBase-ManualInject->NtHeaders->OptionalHeader.ImageBase); // Calculate the delta

    // Relocate the image

    while(pIBR->VirtualAddress)
    {
        if(pIBR->SizeOfBlock>=sizeof(IMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION))
        {
            count=(pIBR->SizeOfBlock-sizeof(IMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION))/sizeof(WORD);
            list=(PWORD)(pIBR+1);

            for(i=0;i<count;i++)
            {
                if(list[i])
                {
                    ptr=(PDWORD)((LPBYTE)ManualInject->ImageBase+(pIBR->VirtualAddress+(list[i] & 0xFFF)));
                    *ptr+=delta;
                }
            }
        }

        pIBR=(PIMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION)((LPBYTE)pIBR+pIBR->SizeOfBlock);
    }

    pIID=ManualInject->ImportDirectory;

    // Resolve DLL imports

    while(pIID->Characteristics)
    {
        OrigFirstThunk=(PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)((LPBYTE)ManualInject->ImageBase+pIID->OriginalFirstThunk);
        FirstThunk=(PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)((LPBYTE)ManualInject->ImageBase+pIID->FirstThunk);

        hModule=ManualInject->fnLoadLibraryA((LPCSTR)ManualInject->ImageBase+pIID->Name);

        if(!hModule)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        while(OrigFirstThunk->u1.AddressOfData)
        {
            if(OrigFirstThunk->u1.Ordinal & IMAGE_ORDINAL_FLAG)
            {
                // Import by ordinal

                Function=(DWORD)ManualInject->fnGetProcAddress(hModule,(LPCSTR)(OrigFirstThunk->u1.Ordinal & 0xFFFF));

                if(!Function)
                {
                    return FALSE;
                }

                FirstThunk->u1.Function=Function;
            }

            else
            {
                // Import by name

                pIBN=(PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME)((LPBYTE)ManualInject->ImageBase+OrigFirstThunk->u1.AddressOfData);
                Function=(DWORD)ManualInject->fnGetProcAddress(hModule,(LPCSTR)pIBN->Name);

                if(!Function)
                {
                    return FALSE;
                }

                FirstThunk->u1.Function=Function;
            }

            OrigFirstThunk++;
            FirstThunk++;
        }

        pIID++;
    }

    if(ManualInject->NtHeaders->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint)
    {
        EntryPoint=(PDLL_MAIN)((LPBYTE)ManualInject->ImageBase+ManualInject->NtHeaders->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint);
        return EntryPoint((HMODULE)ManualInject->ImageBase,DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH,NULL); // Call the entry point
    }

    return TRUE;
}

DWORD WINAPI LoadDllEnd()
{
    return 0;
}

DWORD GetTargetThreadIDFromProcName(const char * ProcName)
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe;
    HANDLE thSnapShot;
    BOOL retval, ProcFound = false;

    thSnapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (thSnapShot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        //MessageBox(NULL, "Error: Unable to create toolhelp snapshot!", "2MLoader", MB_OK); 
        printf("Error: Unable to create toolhelp snapshot!");
        return false;
    }

    pe.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    retval = Process32First(thSnapShot, &pe);
    while (retval)
    {
        if (StrStrI(pe.szExeFile, ProcName))
        {
            return pe.th32ProcessID;
        }
        retval = Process32Next(thSnapShot, &pe);
    }
    return 0;
}

void GetGamePath(char* buff) {
    HKEY hKey = 0;
    char path[255] = { 0 };
    char filename[255] = { 0 };
    DWORD dwType = 0;
    DWORD dwBufSize = 255;

    GetFullPathName("Game.exe", MAX_PATH, buff, NULL);

    //If file exists, then just exit.
    if (FILE *file = fopen(buff, "r")) {
        fclose(file);
        return;
    }

    if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\SomeGame\\Game", 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        bool failed = false;
        dwType = REG_SZ;
        if (RegQueryValueEx(hKey, "PATH", 0, &dwType, (BYTE*)&path, &dwBufSize) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
            failed = true;
        if (RegQueryValueEx(hKey, "FILENAME", 0, &dwType, (BYTE*)&filename, &dwBufSize) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
            failed = true;
        RegCloseKey(hKey);

        sprintf(buff, "%s%s", path, filename);

        if (failed) {
            GetFullPathName("Game.exe", MAX_PATH, buff, NULL);
        }
    }
}

int wmain(int argc,wchar_t* argv[])
{
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pIDH;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pINH;
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER pISH;

    HANDLE hProcess,hThread,hFile,hToken;
    PVOID /*buffer,*/image,mem;
    DWORD i,FileSize,ProcessId,ExitCode,read;

    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
    MANUAL_INJECT ManualInject;

    if(OpenProcessToken((HANDLE)-1,TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES|TOKEN_QUERY,&hToken))
    {
        tp.PrivilegeCount=1;
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes=SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

        tp.Privileges[0].Luid.LowPart=20;
        tp.Privileges[0].Luid.HighPart=0;

        AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken,FALSE,&tp,0,NULL,NULL);
        CloseHandle(hToken);
    }

    printf("\nOpening the DLL.\n");

    /*
    hFile=CreateFile("AO.dll",GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,0,NULL); // Open the DLL

    if(hFile==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("\nError: Unable to open the DLL (%d)\n",GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    FileSize=GetFileSize(hFile,NULL);
    buffer=VirtualAlloc(NULL,FileSize,MEM_COMMIT|MEM_RESERVE,PAGE_READWRITE);

    if(!buffer)
    {
        printf("\nError: Unable to allocate memory for DLL data (%d)\n",GetLastError());

        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return -1;
    }

    // Read the DLL

    if(!ReadFile(hFile,buffer,FileSize,&read,NULL))
    {
        printf("\nError: Unable to read the DLL (%d)\n",GetLastError());

        VirtualFree(buffer,0,MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(hFile);

        return -1;
    }

    CloseHandle(hFile);
    */

    MODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(NULL); // get the handle to the current module (the executable file)
    HRSRC hResource = FindResource(hModule, MAKEINTRESOURCE(RESOURCE_ID), RESOURCE_TYPE); // substitute RESOURCE_ID and RESOURCE_TYPE.
    HGLOBAL hMemory = LoadResource(hModule, hResource);
    DWORD dwSize = SizeofResource(hModule, hResource);
    LPVOID lpAddress = LockResource(hMemory);

    unsigned char *buffer = new char[dwSize];
    memcpy(buffer, lpAddress, dwSize);

    pIDH=(PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)buffer;

    if(pIDH->e_magic!=IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
    {
        printf("\nError: Invalid executable image.\n");

        VirtualFree(buffer,0,MEM_RELEASE);
        return -1;
    }

    pINH=(PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((LPBYTE)buffer+pIDH->e_lfanew);

    if(pINH->Signature!=IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
    {
        printf("\nError: Invalid PE header.\n");

        VirtualFree(buffer,0,MEM_RELEASE);
        return -1;
    }

    if(!(pINH->FileHeader.Characteristics & IMAGE_FILE_DLL))
    {
        printf("\nError: The image is not DLL.\n");

        VirtualFree(buffer,0,MEM_RELEASE);
        return -1;
    }

    // Retrieve process ID 
    ProcessId = 0;
    char buf[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };

    //Game.exe not started, attempt to start Game.exe (same path as this tool).
    if (ProcessId == 0) {
        // Gets the exe's full path name.
        GetGamePath(buf);
        printf("GamePath: ");
        printf(buf);
        printf("\n");
        LPCTSTR lpApplicationName = buf; /* The program to be executed */
        STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo;
        PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInfo;

        memset(&lpStartupInfo, 0, sizeof(lpStartupInfo));
        memset(&lpProcessInfo, 0, sizeof(lpProcessInfo));

        /* Create the process */
        if (!CreateProcess(lpApplicationName, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, &lpStartupInfo, &lpProcessInfo)) {
            printf("Uh-Oh! CreateProcess() failed to start program %s\n", lpApplicationName);
            _getch();
            return 0;
        } else {
            WaitForSingleObject(lpProcessInfo.hProcess, 2000);
            CloseHandle(lpProcessInfo.hThread);
            CloseHandle(lpProcessInfo.hProcess);
            ProcessId = lpProcessInfo.dwProcessId; 
        }
    }
    printf("Game.exe ProcessId = %d\n", ProcessId);

    printf("\nOpening target process.\n");
    hProcess=OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,FALSE,ProcessId);

    if(!hProcess)
    {
        printf("\nError: Unable to open target process (%d)\n",GetLastError());

        VirtualFree(buffer,0,MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(hProcess);

        return -1;
    }

    printf("\nAllocating memory for the DLL.\n");
    image=VirtualAllocEx(hProcess,NULL,pINH->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage,MEM_COMMIT|MEM_RESERVE,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE); // Allocate memory for the DLL

    if(!image)
    {
        printf("\nError: Unable to allocate memory for the DLL (%d)\n",GetLastError());

        VirtualFree(buffer,0,MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(hProcess);

        return -1;
    }

    // Copy the header to target process

    printf("\nCopying headers into target process.\n");

    if(!WriteProcessMemory(hProcess,image,buffer,pINH->OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders,NULL))
    {
        printf("\nError: Unable to copy headers to target process (%d)\n",GetLastError());

        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess,image,0,MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(hProcess);

        VirtualFree(buffer,0,MEM_RELEASE);
        return -1;
    }

    pISH=(PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)(pINH+1);

    // Copy the DLL to target process

    printf("\nCopying sections to target process.\n");

    for(i=0;i<pINH->FileHeader.NumberOfSections;i++)
    {
        WriteProcessMemory(hProcess,(PVOID)((LPBYTE)image+pISH[i].VirtualAddress),(PVOID)((LPBYTE)buffer+pISH[i].PointerToRawData),pISH[i].SizeOfRawData,NULL);
    }

    printf("\nAllocating memory for the loader code.\n");
    mem=VirtualAllocEx(hProcess,NULL,4096,MEM_COMMIT|MEM_RESERVE,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE); // Allocate memory for the loader code

    if(!mem)
    {
        printf("\nError: Unable to allocate memory for the loader code (%d)\n",GetLastError());

        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess,image,0,MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(hProcess);

        VirtualFree(buffer,0,MEM_RELEASE);
        return -1;
    }

    printf("\nLoader code allocated at %#x\n",mem);
    memset(&ManualInject,0,sizeof(MANUAL_INJECT));

    ManualInject.ImageBase=image;
    ManualInject.NtHeaders=(PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((LPBYTE)image+pIDH->e_lfanew);
    ManualInject.BaseRelocation=(PIMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION)((LPBYTE)image+pINH->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BASERELOC].VirtualAddress);
    ManualInject.ImportDirectory=(PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)((LPBYTE)image+pINH->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress);
    ManualInject.fnLoadLibraryA=LoadLibraryA;
    ManualInject.fnGetProcAddress=GetProcAddress;

    printf("\nWriting loader code to target process.\n");

    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess,mem,&ManualInject,sizeof(MANUAL_INJECT),NULL); // Write the loader information to target process
    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess,(PVOID)((PMANUAL_INJECT)mem+1),LoadDll,(DWORD)LoadDllEnd-(DWORD)LoadDll,NULL); // Write the loader code to target process

    printf("\nExecuting loader code.\n");
    hThread=CreateRemoteThread(hProcess,NULL,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)((PMANUAL_INJECT)mem+1),mem,0,NULL); // Create a remote thread to execute the loader code

    if(!hThread)
    {
        printf("\nError: Unable to execute loader code (%d)\n",GetLastError());

        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess,mem,0,MEM_RELEASE);
        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess,image,0,MEM_RELEASE);

        CloseHandle(hProcess);

        VirtualFree(buffer,0,MEM_RELEASE);
        return -1;
    }

    WaitForSingleObject(hThread,INFINITE);
    GetExitCodeThread(hThread,&ExitCode);

    if(!ExitCode)
    {
        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess,mem,0,MEM_RELEASE);
        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess,image,0,MEM_RELEASE);

        CloseHandle(hThread);
        CloseHandle(hProcess);

        VirtualFree(buffer,0,MEM_RELEASE);
        return -1;
    }

    CloseHandle(hThread);
    VirtualFreeEx(hProcess,mem,0,MEM_RELEASE);

    CloseHandle(hProcess);

    printf("\nDLL injected at %#x\n",image);

    if(pINH->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint)
    {
        printf("\nDLL entry point: %#x\n",(PVOID)((LPBYTE)image+pINH->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint));
    }

    VirtualFree(buffer,0,MEM_RELEASE);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get a lot of error when I try to use this. Do I have to make a specific project in Visual Studio to use this code in?

Comment: Yes Console Application Here's the whole project zipped up https://www.mediafire.com/file/9gmo3z8rs53nyr0/ManualInject+DLL+Injector.zip

Comment: how would I inject a DLL from the Resources with this method?

Comment: First you unpack it from resources to a DLL file by writing the file to a disk then you specify the path to the DLL and load it up.. then you could delete DLL file when program is exiting.

Comment: You could also do it without writing the file to the disk, but simply loading it into the buffer where `if(!ReadFile(hFile,buffer,FileSize,&read,NULL))` this line would be replaced with resource buffer load up code

Comment: Updated the code with resouce DLL loading (without writing to disk)

Comment: Find this line `HRSRC hResource = FindResource(hModule, MAKEINTRESOURCE(RESOURCE_ID), RESOURCE_TYPE);` and replace `RESOURCE_ID` with your `RESOURCE ID` and `RESOURCE_TYPE` with your `RESOURCE TYPE` for RESOURCE TYPE  I would use `RT_RCDATA`

Comment: I changed the Resource_Type and the Resource_ID to L"DllName.dll", but I get an error at line 260 saying that MODULE is undefined and at line 266 saying a value of type char* cannot be initialized and entity of type unsigned. When I change MODULE to hModule and remove unsigned from line 266, the program just opnes and closes without any output.

Comment: Resource_ID must be a identifier to your resource. First Resource you import as RCDATA would be `IDR_RT_RCDATA1`, Right click Header Files and click Add select Resource..., in the Add Resource box click Import... and select your DLL file, you might need to change Bitmaps to All Files, Then in Custom Resource Type add `RT_RCDATA` and it will generate the rest.

Comment: I just now got back home to look at this, I tried what you said and I keep getting "Error: Invalid executable image." I put in the resource and added the ID for it as you said.

Comment: this code not works, target app crashes when this line is executed: `hThread=CreateRemoteThread(hProcess,NULL,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)((PMANUAL_INJECT)mem+1),mem,0,NULL);`. Have you fixed? if yes, could share the solution? thank you.